# GPU's driver constantly crashing

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, crash, gpu

Recently I bought used GTX 770. The problem with this card is the crashing driver. I wouldn't mind it but it happens every 5 minutes to 2 hours of gaming. It's very inconsistent and I couldn't find any pattern whatsoever.

What I've done:

- uninstalled previous drivers via DDU
- tried various driver versions (some crash more often than others)
- underclocked and overvolted GPU

Does anyone have an idea what else can I do with it? I can return it, but there aren't many GPUs to buy anyway, so if there's any way that I can eliminate this problem I'd do it.

Event viewer logs:

```
Display driver nvlddmkm stopped responding and has successfully recovered.
```

and

```
\Device\Video8 Graphics Exception: Class 0x0 Subchannel 0x0 Mismatch
```

I have also tried adding *TdrDelay* to registry and setting it to 10 - that did seem to help a little (but that might be a placebo). Driver crashes are a little bit less frequent.

Anyone got an idea what else can I do?

Comment: If the driver is constantly crashing then the graphics card is likely defective and causing the drivers to crash because the card is giving it garbage. Send it back.

Comment: @Mokubai I thought so, but I was hoping to do something to at least reduce it